# I'd like to change screens on my flutter app using the navigation bar that I made below

Tags: android-studio, flutter

I learnt how to make this navigation bar on Youtube for my app but I'm struggling implementing navigation and routing from other tutorials online to the navigation bar that I created.

As you can see below, I've created the bottom navigation bar and called it BottomNavyBar()  [image: it currently looks like this]. As I press each Icon I'd like it to go to a new screen made from a separate dart file to show that each icon goes to a new route.

```
        import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';

void main() => runApp(App());

class App extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Homepage(),
    );
  }
}

class Homepage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomepageState createState() => _HomepageState();
}

class _HomepageState extends State<Homepage> {
  double xOffset = 0;
  double yOffset = 0;
  double scaleFactor = 1;

  bool isDrawerOpen = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AnimatedContainer(
      duration: Duration(microseconds: 250),
      transform: Matrix4.translationValues(xOffset, yOffset, 0)
        ..scale(scaleFactor),
      child: Scaffold(
        body: SafeArea(
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Expanded(
                child: Align(
                  alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                  child: Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      isDrawerOpen
                          ? IconButton(
                              icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back_ios),
                              onPressed: () {
                                setState(() {
                                  xOffset = 0;
                                  yOffset = 0;
                                  scaleFactor = 1;
                                  isDrawerOpen = false;
                                });
                              },
                            )
                          : IconButton(
                              icon: Icon(Icons.menu),
                              onPressed: () {
                                setState(() {
                                  xOffset = 230;
                                  yOffset = 150;
                                  scaleFactor = 0.6;
                                  isDrawerOpen = true;
                                });
                              },
                            ),
                      Text(
                        'nghbrly',
                        style: GoogleFonts.quicksand(
                            color: const Color(0xff8fc6bb), fontSize: 45),
                      ),
                      Image(image: AssetImage('assets/images/letterbox.png')),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavyBar(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class NghbrlySideMenu extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _NghbrlySideMenuState createState() => _NghbrlySideMenuState();
}

class _NghbrlySideMenuState extends State<NghbrlySideMenu> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container();
  }
}

class BottomNavyBar extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _BottomNavyBarState createState() => _BottomNavyBarState();
}

class _BottomNavyBarState extends State<BottomNavyBar> {
  int selectedIndex = 0;
  Color backgroundColor = Colors.white;

  List<NavigationItem> items = [
    NavigationItem(
        Icon(
          const IconData(0xe904, fontFamily: 'nghbrly'),
        ),
        Text('  Borrow')),
    NavigationItem(
        Icon(
          const IconData(0xe9c8, fontFamily: 'nghbrlyfullicons'),
        ),
        Text('    Lend')),
    NavigationItem(
        Icon(
          const IconData(0xe97a, fontFamily: 'nghbrlyfullicons'),
        ),
        Text(' Favorites')),
    NavigationItem(
        Icon(
          const IconData(0xe996, fontFamily: 'nghbrlyfullicons'),
        ),
        Text(' Nghbrs')),
    NavigationItem(
        Icon(
          const IconData(0xe9cc, fontFamily: 'nghbrlyfullicons'),
        ),
        Text('   Cart')),
  ];

  Widget _buildItem(NavigationItem item, bool isSelected) {
    return AnimatedContainer(
      duration: Duration(milliseconds: 270),
      height: double.maxFinite,
      width: isSelected ? 125 : 50,
      padding: isSelected
          ? EdgeInsets.only(left: 16, right: 16)
          : EdgeInsets.only(left: 13, right: 8),
      decoration: isSelected
          ? BoxDecoration(
              color: const Color(0xff8fc6bb),
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(50)))
          : null,
      child: ListView(
        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
        children: <Widget>[
          Row(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              IconTheme(
                data: IconThemeData(
                  size: 24,
                  color: isSelected ? backgroundColor : const Color(0xff655454),
                ),
                child: item.icon,
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 5),
                child: isSelected
                    ? DefaultTextStyle.merge(
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: backgroundColor,
                        ),
                        child: item.title)
                    : Container(),
              )
            ],
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  //int _currentIndex = 0;
  //final List<Widget> _children = [];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      bottom: true,
      child: Container(
        height: 56,
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 8, right: 8, top: 4, bottom: 4),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(color: backgroundColor, boxShadow: [
          BoxShadow(
            color: Colors.white,
            blurRadius: 0,
          )
        ]),
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          children: items.map((item) {
            var itemIndex = items.indexOf(item);

            return GestureDetector(
              onTap: () {
                setState(() {
                  selectedIndex = itemIndex;
                });
              },
              child: _buildItem(item, selectedIndex == itemIndex),
            );
          }).toList(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Another thing that I'd like to find out if possible is, what if I wanted to place the navigation bar below the app heading "nghbrly" like in this picture [image: This is how my design looks from Adobe XD] . I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: I have answer for the first problem,i am not sure about 2nd problem@Mogoai Obi

Answer (score 2):

use this plugin [Presistant_bottom_nav_bar](https://pub.dev/packages/persistent_bottom_nav_bar). you can use the bottomnav bar in every pages.also you can disable the bottomnav in specific screen checkout above link

it very good plugin in my opinion.checkout navgation style in this link.you can change the desgin of bottomnavbar  navBarStyle: NavBarStyle.style9, just change the style9 to whatever number provided by plugin. i believe 15 of them available

You can use your custom icon instead of default icon, also instead of this CupertinoColors.systemPurple you can also use Colors.red kind of this Let me know if it works

```
PersistentTabController _controller =PersistentTabController(initialIndex: 0);

//Screens for each nav items.
  List<Widget> _NavScreens() {
    return [
     Screen1(),
     Screen2(),
     Screen3(),
      Screen4(),
      
    ];
  }


  List<PersistentBottomNavBarItem> _navBarsItems() {
    return [
      PersistentBottomNavBarItem(
       icon: Icon(Icons.home),
        title: ("Borrow"),
        activeColor: CupertinoColors.activeBlue,
        inactiveColor: CupertinoColors.systemGrey,
      ),
      PersistentBottomNavBarItem(
        icon: Icon(Icons.favorite),
        title: ("Lend"),
        activeColor: CupertinoColors.activeGreen,
        inactiveColor: CupertinoColors.systemGrey,
      ),
      PersistentBottomNavBarItem(
        icon: Icon(Icons.person_pin),
        title: ("Favorites"),
        activeColor: CupertinoColors.systemRed,
        inactiveColor: CupertinoColors.systemGrey,
      ),
      PersistentBottomNavBarItem(
        icon: Icon(Icons.local_activity),
        title: ("Cart"),
        activeColor: CupertinoColors.systemIndigo,
        inactiveColor: CupertinoColors.systemGrey,
      ),

    ];
  }
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: PersistentTabView(
        controller: _controller,
        screens: _NavScreens(),
        items: _navBarsItems(),
        confineInSafeArea: true,
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        handleAndroidBackButtonPress: true,
        resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true,
        hideNavigationBarWhenKeyboardShows: true,
        decoration: NavBarDecoration(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
        ),
        popAllScreensOnTapOfSelectedTab: true,
        navBarStyle: NavBarStyle.style9,
      ),
    );
}
```